# How to filter out data within 2 date ranges

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, filter, nodes

Hello I'm trying to filter out data that's not between 2 given dates

I currently have this promise

```
 const p = await new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
    rpCacheWrapper(options)
      .then((res: any) => {
        const date = _.uniq(_.map(res, 'Activity Id'));
        date.filter((each: any) => {
          const timeCompareStartDate = moment(
            each['Start Date '] || ''
          ).isBetween(req.query.start as string, req.query.end as string);
          const timeCompareEndDate = moment(
            each['End Date'] || ''
          ).isBetween(req.query.start as string, req.query.end as string);
          return timeCompareStartDate && timeCompareEndDate;
        });
        resolve(date);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
```

The filter isn't correct I'm trying to figure simple way of filtering out dates that aren't between those two query req.query.end and start

This sample of the data set

```
{
  Value: [
    {
      "Activity Id": "05005413-05",
      "Activity Name": "UNIT 1  ASBESTOS REMOVAL; PERMITS (CSP, FSI, HWP)",
      "Start Date ": "2020-11-09 07:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-05-17 15:00:00.0",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "READY",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", ",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "B2121",
      "Activity Name": "Begin Work Week 2121",
      "Start Date ": "2021-05-24 00:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-05-24 00:00:00.0",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", ",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "05005413-35",
      "Activity Name": "SCAFFOLD SUPPORT TEAM - CARPENTERS & LABORERS",
      "Start Date ": "2020-11-09 06:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-06-03 16:00:00.0",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "READY",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", ",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "04912309-35",
      "Activity Name": "SCAFFOLD SUPPORT TEAM - CARPENTERS & LABORERS",
      "Start Date ": "2020-11-09 06:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-06-30 16:00:00.0",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "READY",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", ",
    },
  ];
}
```

So if the start time if start=21-JUN-2021 end=17-MAY-2021 it should filter out the following from the array

```
   {
      "Activity Id": "B2121",
      "Activity Name": "Begin Work Week 2121",
      "Start Date ": "2021-05-24 00:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-05-24 00:00:00.0",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", ",
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original data source needed a little cleanup and I am not sure if "Start Date " (with the space at the end) was a typo. I treated it as such. The way this filter is set up is to *exclude* items that are in range. Cheers

```js
const data = {
  Value: [{
      "Activity Id": "05005413-05",
      "Activity Name": "UNIT 1  ASBESTOS REMOVAL; PERMITS (CSP, FSI, HWP)",
      "Start Date": "2020-11-09 07:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-05-17 15:00:00.0",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      "Status": "READY",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", ",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "B2121",
      "Activity Name": "Begin Work Week 2121",
      "Start Date": "2021-05-24 00:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-05-24 00:00:00.0",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", ",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "05005413-35",
      "Activity Name": "SCAFFOLD SUPPORT TEAM - CARPENTERS & LABORERS",
      "Start Date": "2020-11-09 06:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-06-03 16:00:00.0",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      "Status": "READY",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", "
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "04912309-35",
      "Activity Name": "SCAFFOLD SUPPORT TEAM - CARPENTERS & LABORERS",
      "Start Date": "2020-11-09 06:00:00.0",
      "End Date": "2021-06-30 16:00:00.0",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      "Status": "READY",
      "Work Pln Factor": ", "
    }
  ]
}

const range = ["2021-05-17", "2021-06-21"];
const filtered = data.Value.filter(e => !(new Date(e["Start Date"]) >= new Date(range[0]) && new Date(e["End Date"]) <= new Date(range[1])));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Yes I'm looking to exclude items that are in range

Comment: const filtered = data.Value.filter(
  (e) =>
    !(new Date(e["Start Date"]) >= new Date(range[0])) ||
    !(new Date(e["End Date"]) <= new Date(range[1]))
);    - Is the to handle the inverse ?

Comment: @MateenKazia - Yes, and I updated the answer. Please mark this as the answer when you get a moment. Thanks